# query builder in symfony2.8

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I faced an error in creating a query to communicate with the database I didn't find a solution which is

I create a query builder to retrieve a data from table named Devis. here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace DevisBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * DevisRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class DevisRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function byDevis($user_id,$enterprise_id)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->select('u')
                ->where('u.user_id = :user_id AND u.enterprise_id = :enterprise_id ')
                ->setParameter('user_id',$user_id)
                ->setParameter('enterprise_id', $enterprise_id);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

}
```

and I wrote in the controller

```
$existed_devis = $em->getRepository('DevisBundle:Devis')->byDevis($user_id,$article->getEntreprise()->getId());
```

the error is :

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 49 near 'user_id = :user_id': Error: Class DevisBundle\Entity\Devis has no field or association named user_id
```

here is my database screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBTiq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You forgot ->from()**

And... In DQL you need to use property names but not database field names.
I think, that your entity looking like this:

```
class Devis 
{

    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = 'User')
      */
    private $user;
    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = 'Enterprise')
      */
    private $enterprise;

}
```

So, you Repository in this case may looks like:

class DevisRepository extends EntityRepository {

```
public function byDevis(User $user, Enterprise $enterprice)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('d')
            ->from('Devis d')
            ->where('d.user = :user AND d.enterprise = :enterprise')
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->setParameter('enterprise', $enterprise);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

}

P.S. If you trying to get user from Users by id, it's more easy to do so:

```
$user = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('YourBundle:User')->find($userId);
if ($user && $user->getEnterprise() == $enterprise) {
    // do smth.
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
->setParameter('u.user_id',$user_id)
```

instead of

```
->setParameter('user_id',$user_id)
```

it may help